# Update attributes unless blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an existing Project record, and I'm importing a CSV file  to update the associated Project attributes. However, often the CSV will contain blank fields and I don't want to overright exisiting attributes if the related CSV field is blank.

Something like this:

```
project.update_attributes(:name => row.field('project_name') unless row.field('project_name').blank?,                                             
                          :owner => row.field('project_owner') unless row.field('project_owner').blank?,
                          :due_date => row.field('project_due_date') unless row.field('project_due_date').blank?)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
project.update_attributes({:name => row.field('project_name'),                                                                         
                          :owner => row.field('project_owner'),
                          :due_date => row.field('project_due_date')}.reject{|k,v| v.blank?})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this **from the controller** if needed:

```
def some_params
    params.permit(:foo, :bar).reject { |_, v| v.blank? }
end
```

In this case the attributes **won't be saved** if they are blank

Comment: nice use of the underscore, this should have more updvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the record, you can also set an attribute to nil (as opposed to blank) in order to exclude it from the updates list. I wouldn't call the following example best practice, but I think it can help clarify what's going on in the background: update_attributes will only attempt to update attributes that are provided in the hash, having a non-nil value.

```
params[:csv] = nil if params[:csv].blank? or (arbitrary other condition)
# now update like normal
if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
  ...
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
attrs = [:name,:owner,:due_date].inject({}) {|res,obj| res[obj] = row.field("project_#{obj}") unless row.field("project_#{obj}").blank? }
project.update_attributes attrs
```

Comment: Agreed, compared to the picked solution.